# pip throwing ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

System info:
UBUNTU - 16.04
Python 2.7 (in global workspace)
Python 3.5.4 ( in virtual environment)

Description:
I have installed ROS in global workspace. And now am trying to use a virtual environment to work on it.

Running the command 'pip', I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abhisek/anaconda2/envs/pytorch35/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
    callback(dist)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

I have tried upgrading setuptools and pip but of no help. 
One thing I notice is that int the traceback it keeps on pointing to /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip. But I dont know how to make things correct.